# giving 8 bit input to Spartan 3E kit

Tags: fpga

I have a Spartan 3E kit. In that kit 4 switches are there, 4 push buttons are there.

For my thesis I require 16 bit input but I convert to 8 bit.

Now my problem is I have 4 switches i  can give input only 4 bits,and other 4 bits with out using push button how can I give input.

Advance thanks if any one have any idea how can I give extra 4 bits using external interface, 
using Spartan 3E  kit.

Answer (score 2):

You have a ton of options available to you:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug230.pdf

Obviously you have the built in buttons and switches you mentioned, and there is a rotary push button, which you could use. Here are some other options that aren't fully built in but you could easily make use of (with the least difficult options first):

**The 43 I/Os** coming from the Hirose 100-pin FX2 Edge Connector, you could hook additional buttons/switches up to these I/Os. Then write VHDL to monitor the I/O just as you would the built in buttons/switches.

**RS-232 Serial ports**, plug it into a serial port on a PC and open up a terminal program to talk to it, and see what happens. Again another vhdl block is required to get it to work, but here is a start on that:

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Xilinx-Boards-and-Kits/Rs232-port-on-Spartan-3-starter-board/td-p/19282

**PS/2 keyboard port**, you could plug a keyboard in, again you would need to add some vhdl logic to actually read the keyboard as demonstrated here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZeutF6d0Z4

**10/100 Ethernet Physical Layer Interface**, you could talk to it over ethernet, looks like the MAC is available as part of the EDK Platform Studio’s Base System Builder, and you can write code on a MicroBlaze softcore to talk ethernet!

Comment: Thank you sir for my help, sir where  Hirose 100-pin FX2 Edge Connector is present.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be able to adjust the input quickly, you can simply use the pushbuttons to latch the switches into their own 4-bit part of your vector. For instance (to read in a 16-bit vector):

```
process(clk)
begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case pushbuttons is
            when "0001" =>
                data(15 downto 12) <= switches;
            when "0010" =>
                data(11 downto 8) <= switches;
            when "0100" =>
                data(7 downto 4) <= switches;
            when "1000" =>
                data(3 downto 0) <= switches;
            when others =>
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

If you only need 8-bit input, just chop off the top-half of the case-statement.

Comment: Thank you sir .I clearly understand the concept. I think it will work.

Comment: Sir but I think as I continuously give 8 bit I will get some problem.my main aim of thesis is to determine heart problem of fetal for that I have to continuously give 200 number of 8 bit signal.Can I give input by using this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you need to input 200 8-bit numbers, I'd just use a serial link instead, and transfer the numbers from a PC. Try out the link about the RS-232 connection in Chris Desjardins answer.